# python list if index value > x then replace the value

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list like `L=[5,10,15,25,30,35,40,45,50]`. I need the resultant list to be like `L=[5,10,15,25,15,10,5,10,15]` i.e the resultant list should be between 5 and 25.

Comment: make it `L = [x for x in L if 5 <= L <= 25 ]`

Comment: I Think i wasn't clear with the question.I will attempt again ..             L1=[5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90]

L2=[5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 20, 15, 10,  5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 20, 15, 10,  5, 15]
More  like L2 is a repeating pattern  between 5 and 25

Answer (score 1):

Basically your input is a list of multiples of 5. And you are asking for the resultant list to be a repetetion between 5 and 25 once you reach a number greater than 25 in your input list. Here is a rough code to print your resultant list assuming no surprises.

```
L1=[5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100]
TL = []
for element in L1:
    if element > 25:
        break
    else:
        TL.append(element)
L2 = []
length = len(TL) - 1
incr = length
decr = length
for i in range(len(L1)):
    if i <= length:
        L2.append(TL[i])
    if  i > length:
        if decr <= length and decr > 0:
            decr = decr - 1
            L2.append(TL[decr])
            if decr == 0:
                incr = 0
                continue
        if incr < length:
            incr = incr + 1
            L2.append(TL[incr])
            if incr == length:
                decr = length
print (L1)
print (L2)
```